# java.library.path error

Tags: java, ocr

Please help me: I'm getting Error While using j4lOCR:

```
 `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x1006dc21, pid=3488, tid=2576

 JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [tess3Wrapper.dll+0x6dc21]

 Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 C:\Azaz-2012\OCR\hs_err_pid3488.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
'
actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file .\tessdatamanager.cpp, line 55
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because the C++ code throws an exception. Java can't "wrap" those.

The exception is thrown because the following assertion is violated:

```
actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES
```

The constant is defined in [tessdatamanager.h](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/browse/tags/release-3.01/ccutil/tessdatamanager.h). It's related to the data files which you need. Make sure the data files you use match your version of tesseract.

Comment: Plese tell me how to fix the bug

Comment: As I said: "Make sure the language data files match your version of tesseract."

Comment: After putting files for same version its still not working and showing same Error.

Comment: What was the solution? Others might have the same problem!

Comment: I am having the same problem right now. What was the solution?